# Is it possible to access the grouping level in an Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet that looks something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to write a formula which accesses the grouping levels (the numbers marked in red)?

The problem is that we have a piece of software which exports a BOM (Bill Of Materials) describing, in a top-down manner, the different articles contained in mechanical product. *The grouping number is the only way to know which level a certain article is on*.

Comment: Short answer, No it is not possible with Formula. Longer answer, if there is a logic behind how they are grouped, then maybe by leveraging that logic one can use a formula to only look at the group that satisfies that logic.

Comment: Accessing in terms to determine Group Level is possible,, but the million dollar question is,, what further U are suppose to with,, please [Edit] your post and be specific all about it!!

Comment: AFAIK, directly no. Indirectly.. that's my proposal. (^_^) | use some extra column (say.. column h, open a group. select cells in column h, put (value) 1. then open another group mark 1 in column I, and so on.. the use if formula to access these rows, or relate it to other formula as needed.  | Please share if this solves(or not) your concern. ( :

Comment: That doesn't work for me since my documents are 30.000+ rows and nested up to 8 levels deep. I'll have to find another workaround. If you make an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

why not try VBA script of macro?

I think this will help:
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).OutlineLevel

Go through the sheet and write this property into cells.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same situation where I want to get a proper usage of the outline level that has been outputted from my application. Then, you need to make a visual basic script in Excel. The vb-script editor can be reached through the Macro editor. A typical code that inserts an additional 2nd column that will contain the level and then goes through a file and fills the column with the correct level can look like this:

```
Sub GetOutlineLevel()
' Initiate where to start. With a header row, typical start is row 2
  RowCount = 2

' Insert a new column B, write "Level" as the title in row 1, 
' and define the width of the column  
  Columns("B:B").Select
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  Cells(1, 2).Value = "Level"
  Columns("B:B").Select
  Selection.ColumnWidth = 5

' Go to the first row you want to analyze
  Cells(RowCount, 1).Activate

' Make a loop to go through all lines that contains data.
' This assumes that there is a continuous row of lines that all have data in the
' first column  
  Do
' Fill the cell in column 2 at the current row with the outline level
    Cells(RowCount, 2).Value = ActiveCell.Rows.OutlineLevel
' Go to the next row
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Cells(RowCount, 1).Activate
' Continue and stop at the first empty row
  Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
End Sub
```

This can then also be extended with other functionality. I kept track of the highest outline level in the loop above, and made as many additional columns as there were levels and then made some logic in each of these columns so that the level structure could be visualilzed.

The insertion of columns looked like this (this included a conditional formatting setting that made cells containing an "X" black):

```
  ColumnsInserted = 0
  Do
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Cells(1, 3).Value = "L" & MaxLevel - ColumnsInserted
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 4
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="X", _
        TextOperator:=xlContains
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    ColumnsInserted = ColumnsInserted + 1
  Loop Until ColumnsInserted = MaxLevel
```

And finally a double looped sequence that filled all the cells in the additional columns with a check against the Level-column and put an "X" in the correct cell. This code looked like this:

```
  FIns = 1
  Do
    RowCount = 2
    Do
      Cells(RowCount, 2 + FIns).Select
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-" & FIns & "]=" & FIns & ",""X"","""")"
      RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Loop Until Cells(RowCount, 1).Value = ""
    FormulaInsert = FormulaInsert + 1
  Loop Until FormulaInsert > MaxLevel
```

I see that the nice indentation of the code above is ruined in the final post, but if you are familiar with some coding, you should be able to get that sorted out in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. The function `GET.CELL()` will help.
`GETCELL` is a special function. An Excel 4 macro function indeed and therefore the file has to saved as .xlsm-File when using it. More infos [here](https://exceloffthegrid.com/using-excel-4-macro-functions/)

1. Define a named range (e.g. `OutlineLevel`) in the top cell of your sheet (e.g. A1) with following formula: `=GET.CELL(28,Sheet1!A1)`
2. in an empty column refer to this named range (`=OutlineLevel`) and copy down the formula.

You will get the level of hierarchy for the corresponding row.

Kudos goes to the quite old proposed solution from GlennUK on the [Mr.Excel Forum](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/calculating-outline-levels-in-excel.227279/post-1112028)